# How can I get error reporting turned on onto Heroku hosting for facebook apps(free)?

Tags: php, heroku

PHP on heroku facebook free apps hosting server is not reporting any error. Is there any way i can turn this error reporting on so that debugging makes easy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if there is a configuration way or not but throw this in:

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);